# ASP.NET MVC - URL Action Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing an app using ASP.NET MVC. I'm in a view that is located at:`/orders/{orderId}`. That view renders just fine. Inside of it though, I have a button inside of a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="/orders/{orderId}/flag" method="post">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Flag</button>
</form>
```

In my controller, I have the following:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Details(string id) 
  {
    var model = Orders.FindById(id);
    return View(model);
  }

  public ActionResult Flag(string id)
  {
    var model = Orders.FindById(id);
    model.Flag();
    return RedirectToAction(
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I use the ASP.NET MVC helpers to generate the path to my flag action? The action in my form is just a template at the moment which won't work. How do I address this scenario in my razor view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Url.Action("Flag", "Orders", new { id = [orderid here] })
```

I recommend using [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC), the you can do:

```
@Url.Action(MVC.Orders.Flag([orderid here])
```

Comment: @atika - Interesting. I haven't used t4mvc before. when I try to use it though, I'm getting types generated instead of methods. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: T4MVC should generate types, so you're not using magic strings, but strongly typed code everywhere.